# React Leaflet: setting a polygon's style dynamically

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How do I change a polygon's color programatically?

The solution I was using for GeoJSONs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888817/react-leaflet-setting-a-geojsons-style-dynamically) doesn't work. Though when I inspect the element, I can see

```
style:{color: "red"}
```

nonetheless, the map shows a blue polygon.

Here's the relevant part of my component:

```
render() {
    const {
        id,
        name,
        geoJSON,
        zoomLevel,
        selectedPlot,
        plotBeingEdited
    } = this.props;
    const markerPosition = position(geoJSON);

    let style = () => {
        return {
            color: 'blue'
        };
    };
    if (selectedPlot === id) {
        style = () => {
            return {
                color: 'red'
            };
        };
    }

    if (zoomLevel > 14 && plotBeingEdited === id) {
        return <PlotPolygon id={id} geoJSON={geoJSON} />;
    } else if (zoomLevel > 14) {
        return (
            <Polygon
                ref="plot"
                style={style()}
                id={id}
                positions={[positions(this.props)]}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.props.selectPlot(id);
                }}
            />
        );
    }
```

Comment: Which polygon lib are you using ? Maybe you need to pass on a 'fill' prop. ref -> https://github.com/peteroid/react-polygon#basic

Comment: I'm importing Polygon from React-Leaflet

Comment: pass on color prop directly : <Polygon color="red" />

Comment: This works: color={selectedPlot === id ? 'red' : 'blue'}

If you want to add an answer with it, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass on color prop as an object:

```
<Polygon
   ...
   color={selectedPlot === id ? 'red' : 'blue'}
/>
```